# Convert object to array in php

Tags: php

I am converting object to array using

```
$data['payment_cheque'] = (array)$data['payment_cheque'];
```

What i Get is

```
    "\u0000*\u0000items": ["2017-04-18","2017-06-28","2017-07-05"]
```

What I want is

```
["2017-04-18","2017-06-28","2017-07-05"]
```

Comment: Why not leave a perfectly usable object as an object?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us what is in `$data['payment_cheque']` we could remove the guess work from our attempts to help you

Comment: @RiggsFolly $data['payment_cheque'] is ["2017-04-18","2017-06-28","2017-07-05"] which is an object

Comment: I am guessing _there I go again_ that whatever is in `$data['payment_cheque']` is actually a JSONString

Comment: Actually `["2017-04-18","2017-06-28","2017-07-05"]` looks like a JSONString representation of ___an array to me___

Comment: JSONString representation of an object would be wrapped in `{}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly do not worry, i got my answer from Bibhudatta Sahoo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this

```
$data['payment_cheque'] =json_decode(json_encode($data['payment_cheque'] ,true),true);
```

Comment: It's good idea to convert obj to array. first convert to json, then convert to array.